# How do I get the "Experience without Dying" portion of the monthly achievement?

Tags: achievements, guild-wars-2

For experience without dying, what counts as dying? If I'm downed, but rally myself, does that reset the counter? What if I die completely, but someone else revives me before I return to a waypoint? And does crafting experience count towards this? What about quest rewards? Achievement experience?
I'm trying to figure out what exactly I need to do to finish up this part of the achievement, and what the best way to go about it would be.

Comment: Wiki says _Progress on Experience Survivor is reset whenever the player disconnects, teleports to a new zone, or dies._
"Die" is actually dead. Getting downed isn't being dead :)

Comment: Wow, I can't even log out or go to a new zone? That's pretty harsh; no wonder I haven't gotten very far in that achievement.

Comment: It's probably quicker to do the dailies every day and get 30 mystic coins, than the monthly which nets 20 coins. Doing both obviously would be nice, but I reckon 100k exp in a single zone would be tough without grinding events. Not sure if it's affected by boosters though.

Comment: Do you know which experience sources count? And I wonder if going in and out of instances, such as dungeons, resets the counter.

Comment: Dungeon would be a considered zoning, as it's an instanced area.

Comment: That's pretty disappointing. I thought my best bet was going to be the 20k exp dungeon reward. Man, that's going to be a tough achievement to get! Do you know if crafting experience counts towards it? That might end up being the easiest way to go.

Comment: @SaintWacko, getting the survivor title is pretty easy when you are higher level. With my lvl 80, I can easily get 100k exp within 15 minutes. The exp bonus from monsters can go up to 800. Combined with its base exp, thats about 1k exp per monster. Killing 100 or so pretty much gets you survivor for the month.

Comment: Oh, wow. I wondered about that. Any idea when the monthly achievement resets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is via crafting. Getting 200K crafting experience is really quite easy and cheap (especially for something like Chef) and you obviously don't have to zone. I can verify that's how I got it.

Comment: While this is still true, Chef as a crafter has been massively modified so it is not as easy to attain high crafting levels quickly anymore. However a combination of two crafting professions will give you the same boost in experience result without the messy possibility of death.

Answer (score 4):

You gain experience faster at higher levels.  I wouldn't worry about working on the achievement until near the end of the month, when you're closer to level 80.

Answer (score 1):

At level 62 ish,  it's a little over 100k exp just to get one level, so If you can go into a level 50-60 zone and just get 1 complete level without dying or leaving it's actually pretty easy.

I did a 40-50 fresh zone I had not been to and decided to go for completing the zone,  avoiding the more dangerous parts first where I might die if I missed a jump while trying to get a vistas and got my 100k exp at 32%, which took me 1 hours 15 minutes.

You also get experience for completing achievements so I had a nice boost from just starting the daily achievements that day too helped a lot, that was at level 52.

As someone stated, you have the entire month and at level 80 it's about 250k exp for 1 level so it's a lot easier then it seems at first.

Crafting experience is based off of your current level by the way, so a higher level character before levelling up a craft would be preferable.